# Kusto time series filter

Tags: azure-data-explorer

Am trying to write a time series based filter for the data below.

```
S.No  Name.       Version.     Time
 1.  Dashboard   20            Apr-01
 2.  Search      20            Apr-02
 3.  Dashboard   21            May-01
 4.  Search      20            May-02
 5.  Search      21            May-03
 6.  Dashboard   22            Jun-01
 7.  Search      20            Jun-02
 8.  Search      22            Jun 02
 9.  Dashboard   23            Jun-05
 10. Search      21            Jun-06
 11. Search      20            Jun-06
```

The filter am looking out is a two-step filter.

Step-1 - (Subset): 
Capture the first occurence time of Dashboard for a version. Consider these are our release dates. We need to find the count of search events from older version that happened after the release of a new version. The version numbers here may not be sequential.

```
  Name.       Version.     Time
  Dashboard   20            Apr-01
  Dashboard   21            May-01
  Dashboard   22            Jun-01
  Dashboard   23            Jun-05
```

Actual Output Required : The number of search entries of version 20, that happened after the release of version 21 (May 01 from sample) and so on... ( search entries of version 21, after the release of version 22 ... )

```
  Outliers        Version       Count
  Search          20             3           //4, 7, 11th rows
  Search          21             1           //10th row
  Search          22             0           //Should be avoided in the output if possible.
```

In SQL we used to write ctes for achieving this resultset. Am new to kusto and dunno how to write sub-queries or temp queries..

Could someone please help me out here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try something like this:

```
datatable(series:int, Name:string, Version:long, Time:datetime)
[
    1,  'Dashboard', 20, datetime(2020-04-01),
    2,  'Search',    20, datetime(2020-04-02),
    3,  'Dashboard', 21, datetime(2020-05-01),
    4,  'Search',    20, datetime(2020-05-02),
    5,  'Search',    21, datetime(2020-05-03),
    6,  'Dashboard', 22, datetime(2020-06-01),
    7,  'Search',    20, datetime(2020-06-02),
    8,  'Search',    22, datetime(2020-06-02),
    9,  'Dashboard', 23, datetime(2020-06-05),
    10, 'Search',    21, datetime(2020-06-06),
    11, 'Search',    20, datetime(2020-06-06),
]
| as T
| where Name == "Dashboard"
| summarize min(Time) by Version = Version - 1, Name
| join kind=leftouter(
    T
    | where Name != "Dashboard"
    | extend Version = Version
) on Version
| where Time > min_Time
| summarize count(), series = strcat_array(make_set(series), ", ") by Outlier = Name1, Version
```

-->

```
| Outlier | Version | count_ | series   |
|---------|---------|--------|----------|
| Search  | 20      | 3      | 4, 7, 11 |
| Search  | 21      | 1      | 10       |
```

Thanks to Yoni.
**Modified with prev instead of version - 1.**

```
| summarize ReleaseDate = min(Time) by cV = Version, Name
| sort by ReleaseDate asc
| extend Version  = prev(cV)
| join kind=leftouter(
    T
    | where Name != "Dashboard"
    | extend Version = Version
) on Version
| where Time > ReleaseDate
| summarize count(), series = strcat_array(make_set(series), ", ") by Outlier = Name1, Version
```

Comment: Is there a way to take the previous version without subtracting -1 ? Your solution fits all except one thing, the releases in my case are not sequential....

Comment: looks like you've already modified the answer to include that